# sending email from different module with different detail using single queue, Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, email, queue

I'm new to Laravel and quite confuse how to use queueable emails.
My goal is to send email from different modules with different details using single queue email class.
for example:
I have 3 controllers and 3 different email body where I'm preparing array of details according to scenario and pass it queue email along location (request comes from which controller).
the handle method send the email but the body of email is keeping same which is not fulfil my goal.

**ScreeningController:**
$details array in which provided data and $location variable which shows passing from status function.

```
$details = [
            'title' => 'Mail from Global Screening Database',
            'subject'   => 'Screening Result Declared',
            'to'    => $final_field_office_email,
            'cc'    => 'adil.shahzad@irp.org.pk',
            //'cc'    => $cc_emails,
            'employee_name' => $screening_data->Employee_info->employee_name,
            'reference_no'  => $screening_data->reference_no,
            'nic'   => $screening_data->Employee_info->nic,
            'region'    => $screening_data->regionId->name,
            'field_office'    => $screening_data->field_office->name,

            'staff_type'    => $screening_data->type_of_staff,
            'designation'    => $screening_data->designationsId->name,
            'department'    => $screening_data->departmentsId->name,
            'line_manager'    => $screening_data->lineManagerDesignationsId->name,
            'status'    => 'Completed',
            'result'    => $screening_data->screening_result,
            'screening_date'    => $screening_data->screening_date
        ];

        $location = 'status';

        $job = (new SendQueueEmail($details, $location))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(5));
        
        dispatch($job);
```

**EmployeeController**
$details array in which provided data and $location variable which shows passing from add function.

```
$details = [
                'title' => 'Mail from Global Screening Database',
                'subject'   => 'New Screening record has been include in GSD',
                'to'    => $final_field_office_email,
                //'cc'    => $cc_emails,
                'employee_name' => $screening_data_loop->Employee_info->employee_name,
                'reference_no'  => $screening_data_loop->reference_no,
                'nic'   => $screening_data_loop->Employee_info->nic,
                'region'    => $screening_data_loop->regionId->name,
                'field_office'    => $screening_data_loop->field_office->name,

                'staff_type'    => $screening_data_loop->type_of_staff,
                'designation'    => $screening_data_loop->designationsId->name,
                'department'    => $screening_data_loop->departmentsId->name,
                'line_manager'    => $screening_data_loop->lineManagerDesignationsId->name,
                'status'    => 'Pending',
            ];

            
            $location = 'add';

            $job = (new SendQueueEmail($details, $location))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(5));
            
            dispatch($job);
```

Now the SendQueEmail class

```
namespace App\Jobs;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendQueueEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $details;
    protected $location;
    public $timeout = 120; // 2 hours

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details, $location)
    {
        //
        $this->details = $details;
        $this->location = $location;
        //dd($this->details);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        
        if ($this->location == 'status')
        {
            Mail::send('emails.email_screening_status', [], function($message) {
                $message->to($this->details['to']);
                //$message->cc($details['cc']);
                $message->subject($this->details['subject']);
                //$message->subject($details['message']);
            });
        }
        elseif ($this->location == 'add')
        {
            Mail::send('emails.email_add_screening', [], function($message) {
                $message->to($this->details['to']);
                //$message->cc($details['cc']);
                $message->subject($this->details['subject']);
                //$message->subject($details['message']);
            });
        }
        elseif ($this->location == 'comment')
        {
            Mail::send('emails.email_insert_comment', [], function($message) {
                $message->to($this->details['to']);
                //$message->cc($details['cc']);
                $message->subject($this->details['subject']);
                //$message->subject($details['message']);
            });
        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `Job Middleware` read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#job-middleware

Comment: Where you are passing view?

Comment: The view (mail body) should return from "Mail", I mean from `app/mail/Your mail File` you created. In your mail file, you can return view() from `build method`.

Comment: yes actually i am not return it, so I used mailable class and return it, I also post my answer which works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The job must have a return so I use mailable class more in order to achieve result. Little change in SendQueueEmail file and add Mailable class.

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Mail\ScreeningInsertionEmailQueueSend;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;




class SendQueueEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $details;
    protected $location;
    public $timeout = 120; // 2 hours

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details, $location)
    {
        //
        $this->details = $details;
        $this->location = $location;
        //dd($this->details);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        
        if ($this->location == 'status')
        {
            /*Mail::send('emails.email_screening_status', [], function($message) {
                $message->to($this->details['to']);
                //$message->cc($details['cc']);
                $message->subject($this->details['subject']);
                //$message->subject($details['message']);
            });*/
            $email_status = new ScreeningInsertionEmailQueueSend($this->details, $this->location);
            Mail::to($this->details['to'])->send($email_status);
        }
        elseif ($this->location == 'add')
        {
            $email = new ScreeningInsertionEmailQueueSend($this->details, $this->location);
            Mail::to($this->details['to'])->send($email);

        }
        elseif ($this->location == 'comment')
        {
            /*Mail::send('emails.email_insert_comment', [], function($message) {
                $message->to($this->details['to']);
                //$message->cc($details['cc']);
                $message->subject($this->details['subject']);
                //$message->subject($details['message']);
            });*/
            $email_comment = new ScreeningInsertionEmailQueueSend($this->details, $this->location);
            Mail::to($this->details['to'])->send($email_comment);
        }

        
    }
}
```

and add Mailable class which extends from mail

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ScreeningInsertionEmailQueueSend extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $location;
    protected $details;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details, $location)
    {
        //
        $this->details = $details;
        $this->location = $location;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        if ($this->location == 'status')
        {
            return $this->subject($this->details['subject'])
                ->view('emails.email_screening_status')
                ->with('details', $this->details);
        }
        elseif ($this->location == 'add')
        {
            return $this->subject($this->details['subject'])
                ->view('emails.email_add_screening')
                ->with('details', $this->details);
        }
        elseif ($this->location == 'comment')
        {
            return $this->subject($this->details['subject'])
                ->view('emails.email_insert_comment')
                ->with('details', $this->details);
        }
        
    }
}
```